# What is the best instrument amplifier to measure microvolt dc signals from a low impedance differential type T thermocouple system?

Tags: voltage, measurement

I wish to measure 0.02 C difference between two type T thermocouple junctions with accuracy. I need only 1Hz bandwidth. I am looking for small changes in temperature in this apparatus.

Comment: Do you have thermocouples that accurate?

Comment: That's RTD accuracy, not thermocouple accuracy. I do understand the desire for the thermocouple since you want to measure a temperature difference, but I don't think thermocouples are that repeatable either.

Answer (score 2):

Use a "zero-drift" amplifier with as low noise as possible and acceptable drift. You are looking for about 800nV difference, so pick something with low DC-10Hz or DC-1Hz peak-to-peak noise. Your source will be low impedance so you don't need to worry too much about current noise.

A regular op-amp will be better than an instrumentation amplifier most likely depending on grounding and such like, you should only use an instrumentation amplifier if you have no other options.

Looking at Digikey, I see around 100 options, you can either start looking at datasheets individually, or go to manufacturer websites where they may include noise in the parameters. There are only a few manufacturers of suitable products so that's not as big a burden as it might seem. The cheapest listed is the LTC2054 with 30nV/°C maximum drift and **typical** (no maximum) 600nVp-p 0-1Hz noise.

Beyond the scope of this answer, but you will have to be exquisitely careful to minimize thermal EMFs and thermal gradients to get useful performance at this level. Read any and all application notes you can find before beginning construction. Sub-microvolt DC measurements are closer to a physics experiment than routine electronics design.

Answer (score 1):

[July 2 edited the error budget down, from 0.2 C to 0.01 C]

At the levels of stability you want, the Thermal environment is more important than which OpAmp or INA you select.

For accuracy and stability and calibration benefit, you need thermal control of the PCB. Why? I've read copper-copper junctions (such as PCB plating of vias to join surface foil) produce 0.5uV per ° C.

How serious is this? A type-K thermocouple produces about 40 microVolts per degree C output change. That is 0.025 ° C per uV.

Thus your error budget, total, is about [was 0.2] 0.01 ° C stability. You need to develop your own error budget, including all error sources.

The F-4 Phantom had an Inertial Navigation System that required 15 minutes heat-up time (to stabilize the electronics and mechanical platform at 70 ° C), whereupon the F-4 INS would be aligned with the local directional vectors painted on the runways. The INS was temperature-stabilized at 70 +-1 ° C.

How to do this? Can you achieve your 0.02 degree "temperature difference" resolution without literally controlling the temperature?

Possibly. If you have ZERO thermal gradients between the thermocouple input connectors, and/or those thermal gradients change by < 0.02 ° C, then an unheated_PCB approach may be possible.

- You want to create thermal_shorts around any amplifiers or ADCs or traces from the input connectors, etc. The thermal_shorts **AROUND** the circuit is the only way I know to avoid thermal_gradients.

Thermal shorts, in my practice (successful, for thermocouple work), are built using several Ground Planes behind the electronics, with dozens of vias connecting all the Ground Planes together.

The thermal resistance of standard thickness copper PCB foil is 70 (7-0) ° C per watt per square of foil, for any size square. A mere 0.001 watt change in heat flow will cause 0.07 degree C change.

- And very low power dissipation from your electronics.
- And very low heat flux from the outside; even your face radiates heat, which ensures your lab measurements will never be consistent unless **YOU** are far away.
- You need a highly thermal_conductive heat shield around your system; this may be thick copper metal.
- Outside of all, is a thermal_insulator/reflector, so the external (People, windows, air_conditioning, etc) changes do not dump changes in heat flux that overload the thermal_conductive heat shield
- Another tool for thermally_precise use of Integrated Circuits is ---- do not swap around which on_chip output transistor does the work. You achieve this by loading the IC with a fixed load to either rail (Gnd or VDD). This imbalance is used to ensure only the Pulldown device, or the Pullup device, provides the output current.
- Another tool is EMI/RFI filtering. You don't want the voice of a local Disc Jocky to be the variable biasing (through RF rectification in the input stage of the amplifier) of your circuit. Keep the RF out..

Another tool is fast thermal timeconstants. This requires tiny packages.

A square centimeter of PCB foil has a timeconstant, from edge, across those 10 mm, to opposite edge, of 1.14 seconds.

A PCB of size 10cm by 10cm has a thermal timeconstant of 100X (1-0-0) the 1cm square. This is 114 seconds to stabilize to 63% of the final temperature.

To minimize the heat-changes, use high value resistors. Which conflicts with the low_value resistors requires to achive low thermal_noise.

Now let us examine the thermal noise budget.

Assume you need about 0.1 microvolt PeakPeak Referred_To_Input random noise.
Which is about 0.1/6 = 0.016 uV or 16 nanoVolts RMS total noise.

Assume your opamp has an Rnoise of 62 ohms (which means 1 nanoVolt/rtHertz noise density). We'll assume the parallel equivalent of your gain-set resistors is also 62 ohm ---- 68 and 680 ohms, giving a gain of 11X, will do this. This sounds easy; we'll have total input_referred_noise of RMS(1nV and 1nV) = 1.414 nanoVolt/rtHz. The 16nanoVolt budget would allow (16/1.414)^2 or about 150 Hertz bandwidth.

Unfortunately the silicon surface has flaws, and charges occupy those flaws and the charges will randomly leave their own private flaw, and then return. This creates 1/F random noise, and this over_rides the flat_random noise.